# jQuery popup box on returning result from a struts action class

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I have a jsp page which maps to struts.xml where in an action class, it checks from the DB whether the Id and password are correct. If they are correct, it maps to the corret page. I want if it does not map, then a jQuery popup should be there saying, Incorrect Id or password!

**HTML CODE**

```
    <form action="alreadylogin" method="post">
                Enter your Email Id&nbsp;<input type="email" name="loginemail"  placeholder="Enter Your Email Id" required  ><br><br>

                Enter your Password&nbsp;<input type="password" name="loginpass" placeholder="Enter your Password" required ><br><br>

                <input type="reset" value="Reset">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

ACTION CLASS: The action class here shows the action mapped from STRUTS.XML

```
    public String execute()
    {  
        String check=null;

        try {
            ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("select userpass,firstname from register where usermail='"+ loginemail +"'");

            while (r.next()) {
                String psw=r.getString(1);
                String name=r.getString(2);

                jname=name;

                if(psw.equals(loginpass))
                {
                    session.put("S3CRET", "S3CRET");
                    session.put("USERNAME", jname);
                    check="success";
                }
                        else
                {
                    check="input";
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            return check;
        }
```

How can apply a jQuery popup here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already submitting to a page; using a jQuery popup no longer makes any sense
since you'll either forward or redirect coming back anyway–just show the
appropriate message in the INPUT result page.

Jorge's answer is appropriate if you *really* think the additional work is necessary. If you want to avoid a page refresh then use the JSON plugin and return only a JSON response. This adds a level of complexity it doesn't appear you're ready for.

---

Here are a bunch of unrelated comments.

```
ResultSet r = 
  st.executeQuery("select userpass, firstname from register where usermail='" + loginemail + "'");
```

This is an invitation for SQL injection. Do not do this; use a prepared statement.

```
String name = r.getString(2);
jname = name;

if (psw.equals(loginpass)) {
    session.put("S3CRET", "S3CRET");
    session.put("USERNAME", jname);
```

There is no reason to use `jname` here. You already have `name`; put it in session, e.g.,

```
String name = r.getString(2);
if (psw.equals(loginpass)) {
    session.put("USERNAME", name);
```

There is no reason to put the password into session at all.

I do not believe it is valuable to have only a single return statement in a method this short.
Just return the appropriate result as soon as you possibly can and allow faster reasoning about
the method.

```
public String execute() { 
    String name; 
    ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("select userpass,firstname from register where usermail='" + loginemail + "'");
    while (r.next()) {
        if (!psw.equals(loginpass)) {
            return INPUT;
        }

        name = r.getString(2);
    }

    session.put("USERNAME", name);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

None of this should be happening in the `execute` method. Methods should all operate at the same level
of abstraction, do only a single thing, and do it completely. The execute method should do little more
than check for a valid login and return the appropriate result, something closer to:

```
public String execute() {
    return loginService.login(email, password) ? SUCCESS : INPUT;
}
```

`login` should exist in a service injected into the action, or at *least* in a separate method in the
action class. I cannot recommend the latter; for more details search for anything related to "inversion
of control", "dependency injection", "writing testable Java code", and so on.

Comment: The scope of the NAME is inside the while loop so i cannot return SUCCESS and put the NAME in session.

Comment: @AmanTaneja ... Use your head; declare it outside the loop. Edited to reflect, but of all the issues shown, that's trivial.

Comment: Insert Finally to complete the block statements. If I return anything in the finally block, that shall be passed to struts.XML, and it will happen irrespective of the conditions. That was the reason for using CHECK!

Comment: @AmanTaneja What's the `finally` error? There's no `finally` in my code. The DB code is properly isolated in a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a login interceptor for this??

Anyways, in my opinion it's always easier to use the framework's validation with the `addFieldError(fieldName, errorMsg)` function. Make sure your action class extends ActionSupport and try this just before you do `check="input";` :

```
..
 else
 {
  addFieldError("loginpass", "Wrong email/password"); //add this new line
  check="input"; //this was the line you wrote
 }
..
```

This will render the "wrong email/password" message just above the password input.

If you still want to make a JQuery popup appear, I think maybe you could set a new `boolean` inside the action to represent if the login went OK or not. Then, when the page loads again after `INPUT` was returned, check that var and if login went wrong launch the popup.

I'm also still new to struts2 but I hope that may help.

### **EDIT:**

**struts.xml action mapping**

```
<action name="alreadylogin"
        class="full.path.to.action.class">
        <result name="success"> index.jsp</result> <!--Page where you redirect if Login is OK -->
        <result name="input">login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**login.jsp:** This represents your current page for logging in

```
<tr><td id="error"><s:fielderror/></td></tr>
<s:form action="alreadylogin" theme="simple">
            Enter your Email Id&nbsp;<s:textfield type="email" name="loginemail"  placeholder="Enter your Email Id" required><br><br>

            Enter your Password&nbsp;<s:textfield type="password" name="loginpass" placeholder="Enter your Password" required><br><br>

            <input type="reset" value="Reset">&nbsp;&nbsp; <!-- I would reset things using JQuery, I don't know how you're reseting this form so I leave it the way you posted it-->
            <s:submit value="%{'Submit'}">
</s:form>
```

**ACTION CLASS** make it extend ActionSupport if possible

```
public class yourActionClass extends ActionSupport{
...

public String execute()
{  
    //String check=null; //you won't need this anymore

    try {
        ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("select userpass,firstname from register where usermail='"+ loginemail +"'");

        while (r.next()) {
            String psw=r.getString(1);
            String name=r.getString(2);

            jname=name;

            if(psw.equals(loginpass))
            {
                session.put("S3CRET", "S3CRET");
                session.put("USERNAME", jname);
                return SUCCESS; //this is why you extend actionsupport
            }
                    else
            {
                addFieldError("loginpass", "Wrong email/password");
                return INPUT;
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){/*Do something if exception is thrown */}
   /* finally
    {
        return check; //this is not needed either as we implement ActionSupport
    }*/ 

/*Here you can implement the validate() method if you need validation. If needed, we'll talk about it*/
...
}
```

This would reload login.jsp if there's any errors during login and will redirect to index.jsp if login went OK. I left the action code as much your way as I could =) .

Comment: UNACCEPTED! @DaveNewton

Comment: @Aman First: Does your action extends ActionSupport or implement Validateable??

If it does, check your JSP code and add this just above the login form:

    `<tr><td id="error"><s:fielderror/></td></tr>`

Kind of a workaround for now because I'm a little busy, I'll help you later in the afternoon cos you accepted my answer, but you should have tested it before!

Comment: @AmanTaneja I'm not saying to unaccept it--it's still correct since your options are limited if you really want to redirect/forward *and* open a dialog.

Comment: The code worked. However, the number of times i keep entering the wrong password, the error messages get stacked, one after the other. It there a way to remove them, whenever a form resubmits!

Comment: Could you please post the action mapping on your `struts.xml` file? You're doing things a little out of the way I'm used to see on struts2, why don't you use a `<s:form/>` which is easier?